# Срочно увеличить порог неутверждаемой правки чужих сообщений

Tags: предложение

Огромная просьба модераторам поднять ценз привилегии проведения правки чужих вопросов-ответов без одобрения сообщества. До 5000 очков хотя бы. Или вообще до бесконечности.

Я методично боролся с вандальной правкой на протяжении всего времени, но сейчас любители переврать чужую мысль вышли за 1000 - и их правка перешла в разряд неконтролируемых, просматривать всё у меня нет возможности (ни технической, ни по времени), а надо бы.

Comment: Пример перевранной чужой мысли: http://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/418152/revisions

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну так разве на такую правку одобрения не нашлось бы?

Comment: @cnst вы о какой по счетку правке говорите?

Comment: @cnst, не столь важно о чем говорит Nick Volynkin, он вообще о ченм-то своем... (Не знаю, программист, что ли, на нашу голову свалившийся), но суть проблемы в том, что несколько человек просто горят желанием переделать авторский текст чтобы было "покрасивше", не понимая при этом авторского замысла. Сейчас, правда, меньше такой самодеятельности стало - да и я как-то научился перехватывать и откатывать.

Comment: @behemothus там участник убрал кучу бессмысленных смайликов. Вы откатили его правку, а потом сделали точно такую же. В чем смысл? А вот в чем. Насколько я вижу ситуацию, вы просто систематически травите различных участников: минусуете вопросы и ответы, откатываете правки, жалуетесь на Мете. Но вам этого недостаточно и вы хотите, чтобы вообще все правки на сайте проходили через ваши руки. К счастью, полной цензуры вам никогда не предоставят. Любое предложение изменить порог репутации для привилегии, особенно настолько необоснованное, будет отвергнуто или проигнорировано — что и происходит.

Comment: Я в аподщобном тоне ине намерен с Вами общаться.

Comment: Я в подобном тоне не намерен с Вами общаться. Кто бы Вы там ни были, но Ваши инсинуации Выглядят довольно жалко. На самом деле Вы просто мелко мстите мне за то, что я не дал отпор Вашим попыткам затроллить ресурс.

Comment: (+)Господи, если этот гражданин действительно представляет лицо ресурса - или хотя бы за техническую часть отвечает, то неужели на него управы нет?

Answer (score 7):

Привилегия «править сообщения без проверки» — это стандартный режим работы сайта. А порча содержимого — исключительная ситуация, поэтому для нее используется специальный механизм для исключительных ситуаций — тревоги.

Если пользователь правками вандализирует содержимое вопроса или ответа, просто используйте тревогу «требуется вмешательство модератора». Модератор может закрыть участнику возможность править чужие сообщения — на время или навсегда.

Повышение порога произойдет, когда (и если) этот сайт пройдет аттестацию. Тогда для правки сообщения без проверки потребуется 2000 репутации.

Повышение порога вне этого механизма совершенно точно не произойдет и в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: Несколько человек рвз за разои искажают смыс вопроса. Пока у них было меньше 1000 они попадали на проверку. Мне в тои чмле. Сейчас я этого не могу делать. Потому что вылезли за 1000. И за 2000 вылезут, ставя плюсики друг другу. А вы мне тут рассказываете как это работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот увидела - и не поленилась проверить сейчас несколько сообщений подобного рода... 
Ужас. Порог действительно надо повышать, а не рассуждать.

Comment: Рассуждать тоже надо)))

Comment: Послушайте, Вы, Я на ресурсе 4 года, Ирину знаю в реале, на ресурсе - она года три тоже. Вас вообще не знаю, что Вы тут делаете, простите, со своими советами?!